# What is correct syntax for arrays in powershell?

Tags: arrays, powershell, powershell-2.0

Example1:

> Note 2: The comma is also used so
>   separate items in an array {0,-30}

Example2:

> To create an array, we create a
>   variable and assign the array. Arrays
>   are noted by the “@” symbol. Let’s
>   take the discussion above and use an
>   array to connect to multiple remote
>   computers: $strComputers =
>   @(“Server1″, “Server2″, “Server3″)

So, which one is correct or what is the difference ?

Comment: {0,-30} doesn't create an array, it creates a script block.  It is, however, how an array it typically printed out in the host, as you can see if you run: `New-Object PSObject -Property @{array='a','b','c'}`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Example 2 uses the array cast syntax which allows a single element, for example, to be treated as an array:

```
$myList = @("Hello")
```

Essentially, it allows anything between the parenthesis to be treated as an array including the output from other commands:

```
$myArray = @(Get-Process Excel)
```

Alternatively you can just create an array by specifying a comma separated list:

```
$myArray = "hello", "world", "again"
```

(The curly brackets are not needed)

Comment: You should add the explanation that {} is a script block and not an array, to completely answer the question.

Comment: Also, `@()` is referred to as an `array subexpression` - *Windows PowerShell in Action* pg 119. :-). The second form above `'hello','world','again'` is the "canonical" way to create an array. Array subexpression is typically used to ensure that the result of some expression is an array - either an empty, single element or multiple element array.

Answer (score 3):

You can also attain a single element array by prepending the , operator to a single value:

```
[PS] C:\>$a = ,"Hello World"

[PS] C:\>$a.gettype()


IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     True     Object[]                                 System.Array


[PS] C:\>$a.count

1
```

Comment: good point -- I edited it to indent the code so it shows as code (preformatted) instead of wrapping weird.